# html - background-image not loading image

Tags: html, css

I'm learning how to make a simple fullscreen landing page, and I've ran into a bit of some issues loading the background image.

Directory structure:

```
 fullscreen_test/
 ├── css/
 |   │   
 |   └── landing.css
 ├── images/
 │   └── warehousing-04.jpg
 └── index.html
```

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Landing Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/landing.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="landing">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="content">
                    <h1>Testing</h1>
                    <a class="btn" href="#">What Up</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <h2>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

landing.css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald');

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.landing {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("/images/warehousing-04.jpg") no-repeat;
}
```

I have tried putting the url in double quotes, single quotes, and no quotes, and still no joy. Have tried adding the `/` before the path, and taking it away, same result. Tried using `background` tag as well, also got nothing. Just a big blank space where the image should be. Maybe someone can see the mistake i'm making, because i can't and i've been looking at it for an hour now.

Thanks for any help offered.

Comment: I would expect `url(/fullscreen_test//images/warehousing-04.jpg)` or `url(../images/warehousing-04.jpg)` (relative to css)

Comment: What is the URL to `index.html`? You have absolute paths in your URLs, but we don't know where the root of your site.

Comment: It won't, because the CSS and image are in a different folder and need a relative url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created an fiddle for this.
Have a look

https://jsfiddle.net/cooltammy/c2z2khLq/

Just use with your changed css

```
.landing {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("../images/warehousing-04.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: This is practically the same answer as mine, and the edit to Adaleni's

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't show the code, it shows an absolute URL to an image which is always going to work. The code in your answer is the same as below...

Comment: @AndyHolmes background-image: url("../images/warehousing-04.jpg") no-repeat; this won't work ... you have to use    background-repeat: no-repeat;

Comment: @AndyHolmes and that's the reason you are downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

An explanation, why your approaches didn't work.

Looking at your folder structure:

```
 fullscreen_test/
 ├── css/
 |   │   
 |   └── landing.css
 ├── images/
 │   └── warehousing-04.jpg
 └── index.html
```

Your attempt of

```
background-image: url("/images/warehousing-04.jpg");
```

doesn't work, because `/` goes back to the `root` folder, which in this case is the "folder" containing `fullscreen_test`. So, you are telling your css to load the picture from a folder called `images` which is on the same level as `fullscreen_test`. This folder doesn't exist.

Second approach, removing the slash at the beginning:

```
background-image: url("images/warehousing-04.jpg");
```

Now you are telling css to load the picture from a folder `images` inside the same folder the css is located in. Again, this folder doesn't exist.

The correct solution:

```
background-image: url("../images/warehousing-04.jpg");
```

goes up one level (as indicated by the `..`) from the css folder, so we land back in `fullscreen_test`. Now we are going into the folder `images` (which does exist under `fullscreen_test`) and then load the image.

The second option

```
background-image: url("/fullscreen_test/images/warehousing-04.jpg");
```

will work as well, but it requires you to have that `fullscreen_test` folder present. Judging by the name, it will be removed or renamed in the future, so it isn't as good of a solution as the other one.

Comment: This is what I had as an answer but as Tanmoy correctly pointed out, adding `no-repeat` to `background-image` isn't actually valid so it will still fail to load the image unless you switch the delcaration

Comment: @AndyHolmes: Thanks for pointing it out. I removed it completly as it is unneccessary for the explanation of why OP's approach didn't work, anyway.